# Fill C# ListView with List and SubList

Tags: c#, list, listview, struct

Hi i have 2 structs and i want to fill a listview but the columns that it has i want to use name of product of the `List<SalesProducts>`:

```
struct AgentSalesDetailsList
        {
            public string firstname;
            public string lastname;
            public string phone;
            public string TotalPrice;
            public string transaction_id;
            public List<SalesProducts> Products;

        };
        struct SalesProducts
        {
            public string amount;
            public string ProductName;
        }
```

For example if i have the `AgentSaleDetailsList object myAgent`

```
myAgent.fistname="John";
myAgent.lastname="Jamson";
myAgent.phone = "1234556601";
myAgent.TotalPrice="100$";
myAgent.transaction_id="1";
myAgent.Products={["1","CocaCola"],["2","Sprite"]};
```

And my listview i want to to see something like this:

```
 firstname ---- lastname ---- phone ---- CocaCola ---- Sprite -- TotalPrice 
 John           Jamson     1234556601        1           2          100$
```

but if i had another agent like:

```
myAgent.fistname="John2";
myAgent.lastname="Jamson2";
myAgent.phone = "1234556602";
myAgent.TotalPrice="120$";
myAgent.transaction_id="2";
myAgent.Products={["1","CocaCola"],["2","Sprite"],["1","Lemon"]};
```

i want to see in my listview this:

```
 firstname- lastname - phone - CocaCola -- Sprite ----- lemon -TotalPrice 
 John       Jamson  1234556601     1          2           -       100$
 John2      Jamson2 1234556602     1          2           1       120$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating an adapter class that does the necessary transformation to make your data fit into a list view:

```
public class AgentSalesDetailListViewAdapter
{
    private List<AgentSalesDetailsList> _details;
    private ListView                    _view;
    private ISet<string>                _productNames = new SortedSet<string>();
    private DataTable                   _data         = new DataTable();

    public AgentSalesDetailListViewAdapter(List<AgentSalesDetailsList> details, ListView view)
    {
        _details = details;
        _view    = view;
    }

    public void SetUpView()
    {
        PopulateProductNames();
        PrepareDataColumns();
        FillData();
        FillView();
    }

    private void PopulateProductNames()
    {
        _productNames.Clear();

        // collect all product names into a single set
        foreach ( AgentSalesDetailsList detail in _details )
        {
            foreach ( SalesProducts product in detail.Products )
            {
                _productNames.Add(product.ProductName);
            }
        }
    }

    private void PrepareDataColumns()
    {
        _data.Columns.Clear();
        _view.Columns.Clear();

        // add columns for the needed data to the DataTable
        _data.Columns.Add("firstname");
        _data.Columns.Add("lastname");
        _data.Columns.Add("phone");
        // add a column fo every product in your details list
        foreach ( string productName in _productNames )
        {
            _data.Columns.Add(productName);
        }
        _data.Columns.Add("TotalPrice");

        // now add the same columns to the ListView
        foreach ( DataColumn column in _data.Columns )
        {
            _view.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName);
        }
    }

    private void FillData()
    {
        // fill data table with data from your list
        foreach ( AgentSalesDetailsList detail in _details )
        {
            DataRow row = _data.NewRow();

            row["firstname"] = detail.firstname;
            row["lastname"] = detail.lastname;
            row["phone"] = detail.phone;
            row["TotalPrice"] = detail.TotalPrice;

            // init product columns with -
            foreach ( string productName in _productNames )
            {
                row[productName] = "-";
            }

            // set the product columns
            foreach ( SalesProducts product in detail.Products )
            {
                row[product.ProductName] = product.amount;
            }

            _data.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }

    private void FillView()
    {
        // copy data from table to view
        foreach ( DataRow row in _data.Rows )
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row[0].ToString());
            for ( int i = 1; i < _data.Columns.Count; i++ )
            {
                item.SubItems.Add(row[i].ToString());
            }
            _view.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is pass your agent sales details and your ListView to the adapter's constructor and call `SetUpView()`.